# How to route to a assets folder on parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Im trying to deliver all images inside a assets folder using Node and Express.

**Folder structure:**

```
.
└── src/
    ├── assets/
    │   ├── 01.webp
    │   └── 02.jpg
    └── components/
        ├── Gamegrid.js
        └── testedir/
            ├── 01.webp
            └── 02.jpg
```

**The Gamegrid.js code:**

```
function definirGrid(numeroDeCartas = 12){

    console.log('hei')

    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();
    const PORT = 3001;

    app.use('/testedir', express.static('testedir'));
    app.use(path.join(__dirname,'..','assets'), express.static('assets'));

    app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
        res.send('hello world');
    });
    app.get('/sobre',(req, res)=>{
        res.send('página sobre');
    });

    app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
        console.log('app listening on port',PORT)
    })
}

definirGrid()
```

I'm able to access `http://localhost:3001/testedir/02.jpg` but not `http://localhost:3001/assets/02.jpg`.

How can I route for the `../assets` images?

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```js
var url= 'http://localhost:3001/testedir/02.jpg';
var new_url = url.replace(new RegExp('testedir','g'), 'assets');
console.log(new_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same way as you did with the **testedir** folder.

```
app.use('/testedir', express.static('testedir'));
app.use('/assets', express.static('../assets'));
```

However, I would advise you, to create **one** public folder which may include  all the other folders you want to serve in public.